# How to know, when AJAX request is fully loaded in Native Javascript?

Tags: javascript

It is my AJAX call with setTimeout

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    document.getElementById('mainContent').style.display = 'none';
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        xhttp.onload = function(){
            document.getElementById("mainContent").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            setTimeout(function(
               document.getElementById("mainContent").style.display = 'block';        
            ),1000);
        }
    }
};
xhttp.open("POST", "system.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("lang="+lang);
```

I want detect when ajax is fully loaded and I have also solution here

I have solution here but I can't understand how it work.

```
var oldOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
function onStateChange(event) {
    // fires on every readystatechange ever
    // use `this` to determine which XHR object fired the change event
}

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
    // when an XHR object is opened, add a listener for its readystatechange events
    this.addEventListener("readystatechange", onStateChange)

    // run the real `open`
    oldOpen.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Can you example me how it work or write full code how it work ?

Comment: You don't need to use both `onreadystatechange` and `onload`. The condition `readyState == 4` indicates that the request is completed.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The request is fully loaded when the `onload` function runs.

Comment: When my ajax call get result and I do innerHTML on div, Images still loading.. how I can fix it?

Comment: That's hard. The images can have `onload` attributes that call a function to increment a counter, but unless you know how many images there are, you can't tell when all of them are loaded.

Comment: That has nothing to do with AJAX, it happens any time you're updating the DOM dynamically with images.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, I think I have solution by your answer. ^_^